# SherlockListActivity does not have getSupportFragmentManager method

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have an activity derived from `SherlockListActivity` and I am wanting to show a `SherlockDialogFragment` inside this activity. The `show` method of the dialog instance requires a `SupportFragmentManager`, but it seems that `SherlockListActivity` only has the method `getFragmentManager` and not `getSupportFragmentManager`.

Does anyone know why the method `getSupportFragmentManager` is missing and how I could workaround this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does anyone know why the method getSupportFragmentManager is missing

Because `SherlockListActivity` inherits from `ListActivity`, not from `FragmentActivity`.

> how I could workaround this issue?

Do not use `SherlockListActivity`. Use `SherlockFragmentActivity` and either a `SherlockListFragment` or your own `ListView` management code.

Comment: Thanks, CommonsWare for explaining this. I was hoping that there would be a way to get `SupportFragmentManager` without changing the `SherlockListActivity` to a `SherlockFragmentActivity`, but alas. It is just that I have a base class that I defined that inherited from `FragmentListActivity` and it is working perfectly except for this issue and now I am struggling to get it working correctly with it inheriting from `SherlockFragmentActivity`. But thanks for your response.